# Gitlab CI fails with Error : 2002 Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock

Tags: django, python-3.x, docker, continuous-integration, gitlab

I am running a gitlab CI for my django project with Mysql DB.

And I am getting following error :

```
django.db.utils.OperationalError: (2002, "Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock' (2)"
```

My requirement.txt file is as follows :

```
Django==2.0.4
django-extensions==2.0.6
mysqlclient==1.3.12
```

Here is My CI Config file:

```
# This file is a template, and might need editing before it works on your project.
# Official framework image. Look for the different tagged releases at:
# https://hub.docker.com/r/library/python
image: python:latest

# Pick zero or more services to be used on all builds.
# Only needed when using a docker container to run your tests in.
# Check out: http://docs.gitlab.com/ce/ci/docker/using_docker_images.html#what-is-a-service
services:
  - mysql:latest
 # - postgres:latest

variables:
  # POSTGRES_DB: database_name
  MYSQL_DB: database_name
  MYSQL_ALLOW_EMPTY_PASSWORD: "1"

# This folder is cached between builds
# http://docs.gitlab.com/ce/ci/yaml/README.html#cache
cache:
  paths:
  - ~/.cache/pip/

# This is a basic example for a gem or script which doesn't use
# services such as redis or postgres
before_script:
  - python -V
  # Print out python version for debugging
  # Uncomment next line if your Django app needs a JS runtime:
  # - apt-get update -q && apt-get install nodejs -yqq
  - pip install -r requirements.txt

# To get Django tests to work you may need to create a settings file using
# the following DATABASES:
#
# DATABASES = {
#     'default': {
#        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.postgresql_psycopg2',
#        'NAME': 'ci',
#        'USER': 'postgres',
#        'PASSWORD': 'postgres',
#        'HOST': 'postgres',
#        'PORT': '5432',
#    },
# }
#
# and then adding `--settings app.settings.ci` (or similar) to the test command

test:
  variables:
    # DATABASE_URL: "postgresql://postgres:postgres@postgres:5432/$POSTGRES_DB"
    MYSQL_ALLOW_EMPTY_PASSWORD: "1"
    DATABASE_URL: mysql://root@mysql:3306
  script:
  - python manage.py test
```

And the whole output is:

```
Running with gitlab-runner 10.7.0-rc1 (a4699306)
  on docker-auto-scale 4e4528ca
Using Docker executor with image python:latest ...
Starting service mysql:latest ...
Pulling docker image mysql:latest ...
Using docker image sha256:8d65ec712c69a27e2b9064f2fef307849775687d270e9ab5b79fd17dcd31b16e for mysql:latest ...
Waiting for services to be up and running...
Pulling docker image python:latest ...
Using docker image sha256:6bf7a4fa2d455fae4ce7f38b0b6db33fc5c5ea537c252b0bab8a6338176cb81b for python:latest ...
Running on runner-4e4528ca-project-4802656-concurrent-0 via runner-4e4528ca-srm-1524305095-4dc1df06...
Cloning repository...
Cloning into '/builds/dptks19/..._devel'...
Checking out 3062aac8 as master...
Skipping Git submodules setup
Checking cache for default...
FATAL: file does not exist                         
Failed to extract cache
$ python -V
Python 3.6.5
$ pip install -r requirements.txt
Collecting Django==2.0.4 (from -r requirements.txt (line 1))
  Downloading https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/89/f9/94c20658f0cdecc2b6607811e2c0bb042408a51f589e5ad0cb0eac3236a1/Django-2.0.4-py3-none-any.whl (7.1MB)
Collecting django-extensions==2.0.6 (from -r requirements.txt (line 2))
  Downloading https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/1e/0e/1a5184f7adbd2d28c8329cffd3806c036901d2a6e790c058fc70259bd4da/django_extensions-2.0.6-py2.py3-none-any.whl (217kB)
Collecting mysqlclient==1.3.12 (from -r requirements.txt (line 3))
  Downloading https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/6f/86/bad31f1c1bb0cc99e88ca2adb7cb5c71f7a6540c1bb001480513de76a931/mysqlclient-1.3.12.tar.gz (89kB)
Collecting pytz (from Django==2.0.4->-r requirements.txt (line 1))
  Downloading https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/dc/83/15f7833b70d3e067ca91467ca245bae0f6fe56ddc7451aa0dc5606b120f2/pytz-2018.4-py2.py3-none-any.whl (510kB)
Collecting six>=1.2 (from django-extensions==2.0.6->-r requirements.txt (line 2))
  Downloading https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/67/4b/141a581104b1f6397bfa78ac9d43d8ad29a7ca43ea90a2d863fe3056e86a/six-1.11.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl
Building wheels for collected packages: mysqlclient
  Running setup.py bdist_wheel for mysqlclient: started
  Running setup.py bdist_wheel for mysqlclient: finished with status 'done'
  Stored in directory: /root/.cache/pip/wheels/50/c7/31/81a516762c8e9324f2b1fdffc1e84b9f07224fe3707956f6e1
Successfully built mysqlclient
Installing collected packages: pytz, Django, six, django-extensions, mysqlclient
Successfully installed Django-2.0.4 django-extensions-2.0.6 mysqlclient-1.3.12 pytz-2018.4 six-1.11.0
$ python manage.py test
Creating test database for alias 'default'...
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/backends/base/base.py", line 216, in ensure_connection
    self.connect()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/backends/base/base.py", line 194, in connect
    self.connection = self.get_new_connection(conn_params)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/backends/mysql/base.py", line 236, in get_new_connection
    return Database.connect(**conn_params)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/MySQLdb/__init__.py", line 86, in Connect
    return Connection(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/MySQLdb/connections.py", line 204, in __init__
    super(Connection, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs2)
_mysql_exceptions.OperationalError: (2002, "Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock' (2)")

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "manage.py", line 17, in <module>
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 371, in execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 365, in execute
    self.fetch_command(subcommand).run_from_argv(self.argv)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/management/commands/test.py", line 26, in run_from_argv
    super().run_from_argv(argv)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 288, in run_from_argv
    self.execute(*args, **cmd_options)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 335, in execute
    output = self.handle(*args, **options)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/management/commands/test.py", line 59, in handle
    failures = test_runner.run_tests(test_labels)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/test/runner.py", line 601, in run_tests
    old_config = self.setup_databases()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/test/runner.py", line 548, in setup_databases
    self.parallel, **kwargs
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/test/utils.py", line 176, in setup_databases
    serialize=connection.settings_dict.get('TEST', {}).get('SERIALIZE', True),
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/backends/base/creation.py", line 54, in create_test_db
    self._create_test_db(verbosity, autoclobber, keepdb)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/backends/base/creation.py", line 164, in _create_test_db
    with self._nodb_connection.cursor() as cursor:
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/backends/base/base.py", line 255, in cursor
    return self._cursor()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/backends/base/base.py", line 232, in _cursor
    self.ensure_connection()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/backends/base/base.py", line 216, in ensure_connection
    self.connect()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/utils.py", line 89, in __exit__
    raise dj_exc_value.with_traceback(traceback) from exc_value
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/backends/base/base.py", line 216, in ensure_connection
    self.connect()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/backends/base/base.py", line 194, in connect
    self.connection = self.get_new_connection(conn_params)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/backends/mysql/base.py", line 236, in get_new_connection
    return Database.connect(**conn_params)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/MySQLdb/__init__.py", line 86, in Connect
    return Connection(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/MySQLdb/connections.py", line 204, in __init__
    super(Connection, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs2)
django.db.utils.OperationalError: (2002, "Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock' (2)")
ERROR: Job failed: exit code 1
```

I am trying to run my django project with mysql, locally it is running fine, but when I push any of my code it failes in CI stage.

Any one, what goes wrong?

EDIT:

Settings.py

```
# settings.py
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.mysql',
        'NAME': 'some_db_devel_2',
        'USER': 'root',
        'PASSWORD': '******',
        'HOST': '',
        'PORT': '',
    }
}
```

Comment: https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab-runner/issues/1552

Comment: @vitr, Thanks for link, but I didn't get anything what fails in my case....

Comment: ok, do you actually connect via socket or tcp?

Comment: on my local machine, Socket. default configuration of LAMP. and using mysql for django ....
`
# settings.py
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.mysql',
        'NAME': 'some_db_devel_2',
        'USER': 'root',
        'PASSWORD': '******',
        'HOST': '',
        'PORT': '',
    }
}
`

Comment: show your settings.py that are inside gitlab-ci ... cause it seems django doesnt know where to connect so it uses the default path

Comment: updated in question...

Comment: Do you think this discussion can help? https://forum.gitlab.com/t/gitlab-ci-fails-with-error-2002-cant-connect-to-local-mysql-server-through-socket-var-run-mysqld-mysqld-sock/15472/2